# How to implement redux-search

Tags: redux

I am trying to implement a search filter in my application which uses react/redux using redux-search. The first gotcha I get is when I try to add the store enhancer as in the example.

```js
// Compose :reduxSearch with other store enhancers
const enhancer = compose(
  applyMiddleware(...yourMiddleware),
  reduxSearch({
    // Configure redux-search by telling it which resources to index for searching
    resourceIndexes: {
      // In this example Books will be searchable by :title and :author
      books: ['author', 'title']
    },
    // This selector is responsible for returning each collection of searchable resources
    resourceSelector: (resourceName, state) => {
      // In our example, all resources are stored in the state under a :resources Map
      // For example "books" are stored under state.resources.books
      return state.resources.get(resourceName)
    }
  })
)
```

I understand evarything up to the resourceSelector, when I tried to get a deep dive into the example to see how it works but I can barely see how they are generated and the last line returns an error, **Cannot read property 'get' of undefined**

My state object looks like this

```js
state: {
  //books is an array of objects...each object represents a book
  books:[
  //a book has these properties
  {name, id, author, datePublished}
  ]
}
```

Any help from anyone who understands redux-search is helpful

Answer (score 1):

If this line:

```
return state.resources.get(resourceName)
```

Is causing this error:

> Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

That indicates that `state.resources` is not defined. And sure enough, your state doesn't define a `resources` attribute.

The examples were written with the idea in mind of using `redux-search` to index many types of resources, eg:

```
state: {
  resources: {
    books: [...],
    authors: [...],
    // etc
  }
}
```

The solution to the issue you've reported would be to either:

- A: Add an intermediary `resources` object (if you think you might want to index other things in the future and you like that organization).
- B: Replace `state.resources.get(resourceName)` with `state[resourceName]` or similar.

Comment: Thanks, you have a great library but very few people understand it

Comment: Sorry @brianvaughn if I came off as rude, its been over 2 weeks trying to implement this, kinda frustrating for me, I know the library is good thats why I am trying to understand it.

Comment: It's okay. I get frustrated in situations like that too. I understand.

Comment: Finally got it working, I had to swap the order in my enhancer, I had {applyMiddleware, devToolsExtension, reduxSearch}, swapping the last two got it to work, its pretty awesome, I tried doing my own version with lunr and webworkers but it does not beat this, great library, lots of thanks.

Comment: Happy to hear! :)